# How do I use a function from another file in JS

Tags: node.js, import

I have tried using the below code and get this:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I am trying to import a function from one file into another so I can use it in that other file.

```
// nodeOne.js

async function task() {
console.log('Creating Session');
}

// nodeTwo.js

import { task } from './nodeOne.js';

task();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
// nodeOne.js

async function task() {
console.log('Creating Session');
}

module.exports.task= task

// nodeTwo.js

const { task } = require('./nodeOne.js');

task();
```